# How to pass same JavaScript data to HTML two different ways?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having a hard time passing my JavaScript data to HTML. I can send my video data to iframe so that a search retrieves a list of embedded videos. OR I could set my html var equal to href and display a written list of videos, whose url link redirects to YouTube itself. I want to combine these ideas.

My goal is to display a written list of video titles with thumbnails. When a link is clicked, the video should embed in the current page.

The exact problem is that I expected the onclick functionality to start the playVid function, pass it the video ID data, and send that to the iframe. It didn't. I get uncaught reference error playVid not defined. How is this so?

Update: 
1) Tried to put playVid before showResults. Still undefined though.

2)  Changed onclick="playVid(value.id.videoId)"> to onclick="playVid(' + value.id.videoId + ')">  Still undefined though.

3)
This is the code updating according to your suggestions. It's half-way there. Something gets passed to iframe and the video frame is embedded. playVid is now defined with no problems. The problem is not the data source. It works perfectly before we try to embed. I will post an image of my errors now, which are now about chrome extensions which is weird.

4) I solved the chrome errors I was receiving by installing the Google Cast chrome extension. Apparently Chrome will sometime give errors on embedded YouTube videos unless you download the extension, even if the extension really has nothing to do with embedded videos.

5) Last roadblock seems to be YouTube error "errorCode":"api.invalidparam"

**SOLUTION**

```
function showResults(results) {
    var html = '';
    $.each(results, function(index,value) {
    html += '<li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/' +   value.id.videoId + '"><img src="'  +value.snippet.thumbnails.medium.url +  '">' + value.snippet.title + '</a>)</li>';        });
    $('#results').html(html);
    $('#results li a').click(function(e){
    playVid($(this).attr('href'));
});
}
function playVid(vidID) {
var embedVid = vidID+'?autoplay=1';
document.getElementById('player').src = embedVid;
}
```

Comment: So what is exactly the problem

Comment: I expected the onclick functionality to start the playVid function and send the video data to the iframe, but it doesn't.

Comment: What do you get after clicking the links, and is there any error returned, you can debug errors in the browsers by right click within the page then inspect

Comment: Uncaught reference error playVid is not defined. I don't get how it could be not defined?

Comment: Try to reorder your functions put playVid before showResults

Comment: Still not defined.

Comment: ok it's hard to follow this in comments, i will write some possible solutions in an answer but it's better if you can attach the whole code.

Comment: I think your issue may be with this... `onclick="playVid(value.id.videoId)">`, try change it to... `onclick="playVid(' + value.id.videoId + ')">`

Comment: @Quantumplate you're right, still didn't solve the undefined problem though.

Comment: Sounds like it can't find playVid() so check spelling is correct (no typos) and that method is not defined in the scope of another function, e.g. try put it in it's own script tag... `<script> playVid()... </script>` ... to test.

Comment: Debugging help questions require a [mcve] as per the [help]. Your code does not seem to be minimal. Please [edit] your question to make sure that your code is Minimal (only the code necessary to reproduce your issue in your question), Complete (users do not need anything else to reproduce your issue), and Verifiable (the provided code does reproduce the exact issue you are facing). As it is your question is off-topic for Stack Overflow. Note that this is also a common [downvote reason](http://idownvotedyoubecause.com/so/TooMuchCode).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

1- remove this onclick="playVid(value.id.videoId)" from showResults function and replace it with assigning an id:

```
 html += '<li><a href="#" id="'+value.id.videoId+'"><img src="' + value.snippet.thumbnails.medium.url +  '">' + value.snippet.title + '</a>)</li>';
```

2- add this after the each loop:

```
$('#results').html(html);
$('#results li a').click(function(){
   playVid($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Comment: I get the video embedded in iframe, but lots of errors, in both console and youtube video. Can you please explain number two?

Comment: In your updated code there is no ID attribute in the <a> tag so it may be the problem.

Comment: Andy helped me solve it in another thread. I will edit to show the complete answer to this thread too.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to write the entire iframe tag to the document on click instead of just changing the source of an existing iframe.  First create an outer div @ 800x440 to contain the iframe, and then set

```
outer.innerHTML = '<iframe SRC="' + embedVid + '"></iframe>'
```

Comment: Will give this a try and let you know what happens. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue may be with this line...

```
html += '<li><a href="#" onclick="playVid(value.id.videoId)"><img src="' + value.snippet.thumbnails.medium.url +  '">' + value.snippet.title + '</a>)</li>';
```

Try this instead...

```
html += '<li><a href="#" onclick="playVid(' + value.id.videoId + ')"><img src="' + value.snippet.thumbnails.medium.url +  '">' + value.snippet.title + '</a>)</li>';
```

also try move the playVid() function outside this... `$(function(){`

Comment: playVid is still undefined, although you were right.